# Describe what the following C code implements

Tags: c

doing some  exam prep and the following is a past question.
Describe what the following piece of C code does and rewrite with good programming practices.

```
int g (int *y, unsigned size,int z){
    int tmp = y [0];
    int * b = y+size;
    y[0] = z;
    while(1)
        if(*(--b)==z) { 
            y[0]= tmp; return b-y;
       };
    y[0] = tmp;
    if(tmp == z) 
        return 0;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Cant seem to figure out what its doing, mainly because of the while(1) does that not mean the while loop will run for ever or is the if statement cancelling the while (1). I have never seen this been done before. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try indenting the code first, it helps with readability.

Comment: See `man indent`. It's your friend.

Comment: This function doesn't make sense. The statements starting at `y[0] = tmp;` will never be executed since your `while (1)` loop only exits via a `return`.

Comment: @lurker It's not just the code: in my opinion, the exercise itself doesn't make much sense. I never really understood what's the point of code de-obfuscation exercises.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves It makes a lot of sense if you've ever had to maintain a codebase written by other people.  You'd be surprised how much horrible code is out there, and how often the responsible party is no longer around to explain what it was supposed to do.  This is (sadly) an actual necessary real-life skill in all professional coding environments I have worked in.

Comment: @JohnH, in most cases the guilty party won't be able to explain the code, period. Even if they wrote it last week.

Comment: @JohnH I believe you. I'm still a student, so I have few experience in maintaining long lived codebases. But what you say most definitely makes sense

Comment: See also [What does this following C code implement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203853/what-does-this-following-c-code-implement)  That was a rather poorly designed question — it isn't clear whether the fault is in the question the OP was asked or in the OP's transcription of what was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by lurker gives a good explanation of what the function does, but it doesn't address how to rewrite it into a more maintainable form.

Here's my suggestion:

```
int find_last_occurrence(int y[], unsigned size, int z) {
    int first_pos = y[0];
    int i = size;
    y[0] = z;
    while (y[--i] != z)
      ; /* Intentionally left blank */
    y[0] = first_pos;
    return i;
}
```

Changing `y` from `int *` to `int []` in the arguments list conveys the idea that `y` is an array and not a pointer to an integer. Although it ends up being the same in this specific case, using array notation where an array is expected is generally a good choice.

`tmp` is a poor choice of a variable name, it says nothing about what it holds. `first_pos` is a better description. I also removed pointer arithmetic altogether and used indexing: pointer arithmetic is easy to get wrong, and it is utterly unnecessary here. Plus, it makes it possible to return immediately without having to do any further computation.

One can argue that `while` loops with an empty body can be a bad idea, since we're relying on the loop condition's side effects. I find it easy to read and compact, especially when it is clear that the body is empty and a comment says that it is intentional (however, I am fully expecting disapproving comments on this).

As a final touch, you might want to rename the variables to avoid single-letter variable names.

Answer (score 1):

What the function will do is return the index in `y` of the last element in `y[]` that equals `z` (of size `size`). The default is that it will return `0` since it actually assigns `z` to `y[0]` before the `while (1)` loop. So the `while (1)` is guaranteed to exit when `b == y` if it finds no other `z` in `y[]`.

This is a very confused and poorly written function, by the way, since none of the instructions after the while loop block can ever be reached since the `while (1)` only exits via `return`.

Then the error is that if there is no `z` in the array, it will return `0` implying that there is one at location `0`.

Comment: If by destructive you mean that `y` is written to, then yes, the function is destructive. But note that `y[0]` is restored before returning. This is a subtle detail that I think is worth mentioning.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves ah yes, you're right. I glossed over that. Thanks for pointing it out.