# What does this following C code implement

Tags: c

I am doing a past exam question where i am asked to describe what the following c code implements and re write it with meaningful variables names and good programming practices.

The code is as follows:

```
void h(int ** a, int b){
for(int x=1; x<=b; x++)
  for(y=1; y<=b; y++)
    a[x-1][y-1]= (i/j)*(j/i);
}
```

I dont understand how this code works as:

1) y is never declared in the for loop.

2) the arithmetic of i and j doesn't make sense to me either if i and j are not declared.

I originally thought this was a intake and that i and j are just x and y. But if that was the case the question would have been very easy compared to any other i have already completed.

Comment: Should be sure about a question which you are asking. Otherwise it leaves a lot of permutations and combinations for the 'answerers' to deal with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is probably intended to create an identity matrix with 1's on the leading diagonal and 0's elsewhere.

The Fortran equivalent of that code is used as the first example of bad code in the classic [Elements of Programming Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070342075) by Kernighan and Plauger.

Working from memory, the Fortran code was roughly:

```
       DO 10 I = 1, N
          DO 10 J = 1, N
    10       A(I,J) = (I/J)*(J/I)
```

(There might have been two labels, 10 and 20 say, and one or two continue statements, but I think it was like that. At the time, columns 1-5 were reserved for numeric labels, column 6 was a continuation indicator, and the program occupied columns 7-72, with columns 73-80 being an optional statement sequence number.)

---

Since `y` is used but not declared, if it compiles, `y` must be an external variable (either a global variable or a variable with file scope: `extern int y;` or `int y;` or `static int y;` outside the function).

Since `i` and `j` are used but not declared, if it compiles, they too must be external variables.  And given that neither `i` nor `j` is changed, the same value (either 0 or 1, depending on whether `i != j`) is in fact assigned to each element of `a`.

The more nearly 'correct' code implementing the same (bad) algorithm should be:

```
void h(int **a, int b)
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= b; x++)
        for (int y = 1; y <= b; y++)
            a[x-1][y-1] = (x/y)*(y/x);
}
```

Of course, this is not very C-like, but it does avoid divide-by-zero problems. However, cleaner and simpler code can be written:

```
void h(int **a, int b)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < b; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < b; y++)
            a[x][y] = 0;
        a[x][x] = 1;
    }
}
```

The function should be renamed to something more meaningful.

Comment: It looks to me like it creates a matrix where all the values are the same...  (That, or the OP mistyped it badly.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; No. Its creating an identity matrix for sure.

Comment: okay thank you but how does the undeclared y, i and j work?

Comment: @haccks: That may be the intention, but it's certainly not what it's doing.  It iterates over all matrix values (assuming b*b size), and sets each to `(i/j)*(j/i)` which is, at best, a constant.  (At worst, it's undeclared and so won't compile...)  Of course, this is obviously a typo (either on the part of the OP, or on the part of whomever the OP copied this code from).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; What I mean that if `i` and `j` are replaced by `x` and `y` respectively :)

Comment: Avoiding the large swamp of undefined behavior, what it will probably do on most implementations, assuming it compiles (the variables in question are declared and defined somewhere), is, if `i == j` and neither are zero, it fills an array with the value 1; if `i != j` and neither are 0, the result would be to fill with the value 0, because of integer division rules. If either are 0, it depends on what your particular implementation does with divide-by-zero integer faults. If either are not integers, it gets more interesting...

Comment: @twalberg: thank you, yes — that is pretty much spot on.  The quantity of 'not clear from the question' issues to be handled was…rather large.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer given above, all the undeclared variables should been understood to have been declared in a larger scope. If you are sure that it is indeed `i` and `j` (and both are int) then it will be a zero matrix or a martix of ones(if i = j ).